# logical vs assignment operator precedence in PHP

Tags: php, operator-precedence

Recently i came upon such snippet:

```
$x = 2 && $y = 3; echo (int)$x.':'.(int)$y;
```

Which produces output `1:3`.
By looking at operator [precedence sheet](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) i see that logical operators `||` and `&&` has higher precedence than assignment operator `=`. So first expression should be evaluated as `$x = (2 && $y) = 3;` which becomes `$x = (2 && null) = 3;` and finally evaluates to `$x = false = 3;` Secondly - assignment operator has right associativity, so interpreter should try to execute `false = 3` which is illegal of course. So in my opinion above mentioned code snippet should not compile at all and must throw parse or run-time error. But instead of that script produces 1:3. Which means that interpreter executed actions are:

> a) $y=3
>
> b) 2 && $y
>
> c) $x = (2 && $y)

Why it is so and not according to operator precedence ?

Comment: You can't assign to an expression, so the grouping `(2 && $y) = 3` makes no sense.

Comment: So if some expression makes no sense - we should change operator precedence for being able to extract SOME sense from expression ? What if dynamically changed precedence rules is opposite to developer intentions ? I can only agree that if some expression don't makes sense at all - don't run it or crash it.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ That's PHP for ya…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [operator precedence sheet](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) you link to states as a separate note:

> Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will
>   still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in
>   which case the return value of foo() is put into $a.

So, in effect, an assignment inside an expression will be treated somewhat like a sub-expression. Exactly how and when this will happen isn't clear from the documentation, which just states that "*similar*" expressions will work this way.

Comment: Aron Cederholm is correct that the expression will be broken into sub-expressions and evaluated accordingly. This is determined by the order of the PHP grammar definition. [See here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, i missed that mystical note. This means that from now on I can't trust operator precedence rules anymore.